# Send midi data over a network from inside a host

Tags: c++, networking, midi, vst

How could I send MIDI data received be a VST from inside a Host application (Cubase, for example) over LAN to another computer in the network?

Comment: You should leave the network side of things up to the host application.  There are many solutions for sending MIDI for a network.    For example, Tobias Erichsen's rtpMIDI will work well for this:  http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/rtpMIDI.html

Answer (score 1):

The VST plugin framework does not include an inbuilt solution to send MIDI from one plugin to another. It also goes against the assumption of what VST plugins do. Generally VST plugins only communicate with the host application. It is assumed they will not communicate with other plugins or applications.

That being said you could use [OSC (Open Sound Control)](http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc) and whatever TCP/IP networking library you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

not c++ but java - it is the closest thing i know of though:
[oscvstbridge](http://oscvstbridge.sourceforge.net/%20OscVstBridge%20is%20a%20VST%20plugin%20that,%20as%20the%20name%20implies,%20bridges%20VST%20data%20to%20the%20Open%20Sound%20Control%20%5BOSC%5D%20network%20domain.)